# Dealloc object in OSX project ARC is disable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to do project with Manual Memory Management in Objective-c. I disabled ARC. I developed custom data structure `LinkedList` how can I dealloc this data structure? Should I use **dealloc** or **release** for dealloc object? When I tried dealloc it return me error. Is any memory profiler in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With manual memory management you call `release` when you no longer require an object you own.

The `dealloc` method of an object is called by the system before it is destroyed, it can be used to do cleanup. A `dealloc` method in manual memory management **must** call `[super dealloc]` - this is different from ARC where the super method must not be called.

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much. You know any profiler with memory management in xcode?

Comment: If Xcode's Profile standard Allocations and Leaks (and maybe others) do not meet your needs ask another question and maybe someone can help you.